# PHPExcel Page Border (user defined border)

Tags: border, phpexcel

How to set page border on PHPExcel. 
Couldn't find it ?
This border will be appear before another page created.

and the result after border applied on bottom.
[After Page Border Applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBMlg.png)

I've tried using this

$excel->getDefaultStyle()->applyFromArray($styleArray);

$excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle(
    'A1:' . 
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn() . 
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow()
)->applyFromArray($styleArray);

But no luck... bottom border on page not created...

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

Page border settings are defined through the worksheet's Page Margins object, accessed using `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageMargins()`. There is a section of the developer documentation dedicated to this subject, entitled "[Page margins](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#page-margins)"

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageMargins()
    ->setTop(1)
    ->setRight(0.75)
    ->setLeft(0.75)
    ->setBottom(1.25);
```

Note that this only applies for the Excel2007 and Excel5 Writers

Comment: No It's not working... bottom border before next page not showup...
Maybe because I'm using LibreOffice Calc that has feature to bottom border setting... and Ms Excel doesn't have it.... Is it ?

Comment: So what is a page border then? Please explain exactly what you understand by page border.... as far as MS Excel (and PHPExcel) is concerned, it's a blank section around the edges of the printed page when the worksheet is printed out on paper

Comment: this Spreadsheet created by PHPExcel
http://i.imgur.com/H9RXSHJ.png ....

I want there's a border bottom like this http://i.imgur.com/hne9N9H.png .
.. I created this using libreOffice Calc. 
And I don't know how to make a border like this using PHPExcel ( I call it Border on bottom page) ..

Comment: If it's not an option that's available in MS Excel itself, then it probably won't be supported.... I can only really work with the options available in the OfficeOpenXML or BIFF format specifications, though I can take a look at OASIS to see how it's managed there

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... 
I've been looking this... but I think I've to count on rows and then marking a border on those cell... LOL...
That's my solution... but when users using another printer type, it could be worst... LOL...

Comment: For me the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/29038079/289404 worked perfectly.