# How to use print ready functionality in PHPExcel library

Tags: php, printing, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel library for spreadsheet operations. I am to apply print ready functionality. Does this functionality exist?

Comment: Fixed a grammatical error.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "print ready" functionality?

Comment: Such as size, margin etc.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#setting-printer-options-for-excel-files), particularly the section entitled "**Setting printer options for Excel files**", there's a lot of information about page setup for printing:-

**Orientation and Paper Size:**

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageSetup()
    ->setOrientation(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageSetup()
    ->setPaperSize(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A4);
```

**Page margins:**

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageMargins()->setTop(1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageMargins()->setRight(0.75);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageMargins()->setLeft(0.75);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageMargins()->setBottom(1);
```

**Headers and Footers:**

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getHeaderFooter()
    ->setOddHeader('&C&HPlease treat this document as confidential!');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getHeaderFooter()
    ->setOddFooter('&L&B' . $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->getTitle() .
```

**Printer page breaks:**

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setBreak( 'A10' , PHPExcel_Worksheet::BREAK_ROW );
```

**Showing grid lines:**

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setShowGridlines(true);
```

**Setting rows/columns to repeat at the top/left of each page**

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageSetup()
    ->setRowsToRepeatAtTopByStartAndEnd(1, 5);
```

**Setting the print area:**

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageSetup()
    ->setPrintArea('A1:E5,G4:M20');
```

We write the documentation so that you don't have to ask questions like this

Comment: Sorry if a little OOT. But is there a function to print the excel file? I mean, send it to serverside printer?

Comment: @FandiSusanto - No there isn't, that would be outside the scope of PHPExcel which is simply a library for manipulating spreadsheet files

Comment: @Mark Baker Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56681038/how-do-i-make-a-data-automatically-move-to-a-new-page-if-the-data-is-separate-in